# val_sparse_categorical_accuracy

Tags: keras, tensorflow, accuracy, metric

I know the [metric](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/SparseCategoricalAccuracy) `sparse_categorical_accuracy`

```
Fit model on training data
Epoch 1/2
782/782 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.3485 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9011 - val_loss: 0.1956 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9438
Epoch 2/2
782/782 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.1653 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9514 - val_loss: 0.1340 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9616
```

But

- What is the different between `sparse_categorical_accuracy` and `val_sparse_categorical_accuracy`
- What does it mean if during the training `sparse_categorical_accuracy` is increasing but `val_sparse_categorical_accuracy` seems to be stucked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is simply that the first one is the value calculated on your training dataset, whereas the metric prefixed with 'val' is the value calculated on your test dataset. If the metric on your test dataset is staying the same or decreasing while it is increasing on your training dataset you are overfitting your model on your training dataset, meaning that the model is trying to fit on noise present in the training dataset causing your model to perform worse on out-of-sample data.

Comment: For clarity, "val" is for "validate", as in the validation set. Some people train with train, validate, and test datasets.